# How to filter a dataframe in R but also get the row before and after the filter

Tags: r, filter, subset

Now my problem is that the values are not always matching so I need to also see the line before and after of the dataframe after the filter (basically one row around the filter) so as to make sure Im not missing something. I tried lag and lead and data.table shift but there is always some unnecessary data output that I cant get rid of

I have a file indicating genomic distance that looks like this

| chr | snp | pos | cM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr8 | rs2003497 | 9432942 | 0.0 |
| chr8 | rs1241241 | 9437099 | 0.0 |
| chr8 | rs5262363 | 9440613 | 0.0 |
| chr8 | rs5152525 | 94355216 | 0.0 |
| chr8 | rs5135151 | 94371918 | 0.1 |
| chr8 | rs5253252 | 94374354 | 0.1 |
| chr8 | rs5135151 | 94392948 | 0.0 |

I want to filter based on chr and pos and output the slice.
filter(data, chr == chromosome & pos >= start_pos & pos <= end_pos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first add a couple of filtering markers to your dataset, here `filter_mark` identifies filtered records and `window_mark` leading/lagging rows. During actual subsetting you either include or exclude those extra rows:

```r
library(dplyr)
chromosome <- "chr8"
start_pos  <- 166818 + 1
end_pos    <- 181076 - 1

df_ <- df_ %>% 
  mutate(filter_mark = chr == chromosome & pos >= start_pos & pos <= end_pos,
         window_mark = lag(filter_mark) | lead(filter_mark))

df_ %>% filter(filter_mark | window_mark)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   chr   snp           pos cM    filter_mark window_mark
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>       <lgl>      
#> 1 chr8  rs2003497  166818 NA    FALSE       TRUE       
#> 2 chr8  rs10488368 180568 NA    TRUE        FALSE      
#> 3 chr8  rs10488369 181076 NA    FALSE       TRUE
```

Input data:

```r
df_ <- readr::read_table("
chr snp pos cM
chr8    rs2003497   166818  NA
chr8    rs10488368  180568  NA
chr8    rs10488369  181076  NA")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That works well thanks a lot. but it gives rise to a similar problem I have been encountering with my previous attempts. it does give me the lag and lead values I need but for some reason it also includes values that should be well outside the filter. For example if my start an end inputs are
start_pos  <- 94366068 + 1 
end_pos    <- 94377724 + 1
my output includes the values Im looking 
94355216
94371918
94374354
94392948
for but also
9432942
9437099
9440613
which are all one 0 smaller than the filter but also show up. I assume its a sideeffect of lag and lead?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample from your dataset that could reproduce this, i.e.  output of `dput(yourdf[100:110, ])` where rows 100:110  is the section where this problem occurs.

Comment: ah its a file with 300,000 observations its quite hard to upload a representative sample but the pos column is ordered from 0 to the last coordinate of a chromosome in uneven segments. I have replaced the data table in the post with a datatable you can use to get the above mentioned output

Comment: Is the dataset actually ordered by `pos` ? `lead` and `lag ` do not really deal with values, so "smaller" is bit out of context here. They only operate with vector positions / indeces.

Comment: Yes it is 100% ordered by position and I would also think so so I was very surprised to see an error like this and it only happens when I use lead and lag. I can just ignore those values but I thought I was doing something wrong so wanted to ask for any better suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data seems insufficient to reflect the issue adequately (as per comments), here's some toy data and a *generic solution* to your problem (which, BTW, is a frequent problem or task and where there is suprisingly not yet a neat function available):

**Data**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("B","A","A","A","B","C","B", "A", "C", "A"),
  y = c(1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2)
)
```

**Task**:

Suppose I need to filter all rows where `x == "A" & y > 2` PLUS the immediately surrounding rows (above and below).

**Solution**:

The solution I propose involves writing a function that:

- gets the indices of the filtered rows PLUS those of the surrounding rows:

**Function**:

```
row_sequence <- function(value1, value2) {
  inds <- which(value1 == "A" & value2 > 2)  
  sort(unique(c(inds-1, inds, inds + 1)))
}
```

Now just input the function `row_sequence` into a call to `slice`:

**Implementation**:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  slice(row_sequence(x, y))
  x y
1 A 1
2 A 3   # <- filtered
3 B 1
4 B 1
5 A 5   # <- filtered
6 C 1
```

Comment: Thank you this is the kind of solution I was thinking of implementing by Im not good enough at R to actually implement haha. I unfortunately still run into the same problem as before where I get values that are not technically within the filter because they are one digit smaller. like if in your example you search for value2 > 20 and you also get results for value2 >2. Im not sure why I get this but I can ignore it as I only need the function for manual use. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: If you can post (a part of) your data in reproducible format I can try and adapt the code to it